# Basic Xamarin.iOS Screen Manipulation

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, screen, updates

I am new to Xamarin.iOS programming, so forgive me if this is obvious.

I have a Timer that runs in the Main Application. Among other things, I need it to update fields in the Main.storyboard

In Main.cs:

```
public static void StartTimer()
{
    DateTime startTime;
    startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var dispatcherTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(DispatcherTimer_Tick, startTime, 0, 100);
}

public static void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object state)
{
    GetTime();
    ViewController.SetFieldsTick(Vars.dcounter));
}
```

In the ViewController, I have a routine that updates the screen:

```
public static  void SetFieldsTick(int tick)
{
    switch (tick)
    {
        case 0:     // Display the Time data
        {
            UTC_Data.Text = Vars.DateStrZ;
       }
    }
}
```

If I declare SetFieldsTick as static, then I get the message

> An object reference is required for the non-static field …

for each of the labels that I am trying to update.

If I don't declare it static, then it can refer to the labels, but I get the same error message when calling it in the Main.cs file.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I guess ViewController isn't static that's why you can't call a function from it like that,
anyway your code is a bit difficult to understand, if you want to build an application with a clock or just displaying time take a look at this Xamarin.Forms example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Thanks to DataBinding you don't need to set the UI manually, you should try.

Comment: Yes, but that is using Xamarin.Forms. I am using Xamarin.iOS. There is no DataBinding.

I only included a small snippet of each part of the code. Each of the routines is much larger. The time is just the simplest part. If all I wanted was the time, I could put the timer in the ViewController, but my dispatch routine has to run continuously no matter which screen is active.